# Convert 64bit fixed point to 32bit fixed point

Tags: signal-processing

If for example two numbers are multiplicated, one is in 8.24 format and second is in 2.30 format, product of those two is number with format 10.54, how to go back to 32bit fixed point format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way rounding always works. Remove the trailing 32 digits. Either by actual rounding, or simple truncation. In any way you should arrive at a 10.22 number.

Comment: so you say that if I for example multiplicate 32.0 with 1.31, that will give 33.32 format, so i will need just one shift right to get 1.31?

Comment: no. You can not express a 33.32-number in 1.31. Thats just not possible with any rounding.